# how to integrate signalmaster to already existing expressjs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webrtc

I'm trying to use simplewebrtc in my app, I already have a simple nodejs server with express web framework. But to use simpleWebrtc we have to install [signal master](https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster). I'm looking at the source code for the server.js file in the signal master package but I can't figure out how to combine this server.js with my already existing app.js file. This is basically my app.js

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 
var http = require('http').Server(app); 
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'); 
    console.log("connected to index");
});
```

and this is server.js of signalMaster

```
/*global console*/
var yetify = require('yetify'),
    config = require('getconfig'),
    uuid = require('node-uuid'),
    crypto = require('crypto'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    port = parseInt(process.env.PORT || config.server.port, 10),
    server_handler = function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
    },
    server = null;

// Create an http(s) server instance to that socket.io can listen to
if (config.server.secure) {
    server = require('https').Server({
        key: fs.readFileSync(config.server.key),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(config.server.cert),
        passphrase: config.server.password
    }, server_handler);
} else {
    server = require('http').Server(server_handler);
} 
server.listen(port);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

if (config.logLevel) {
    // https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO
    io.set('log level', config.logLevel);
}
```

etc, etc you can look at the rest by downloading the zip. I thought it would be just replacing server with http, but the server=null doesn't really make sense. All the dependencies are in the directory of the signalMaster unzipped file. I was reading about signalMaster [here](https://simplewebrtc.com/notsosimple.html).

Answer (score 1):

You will need something like this

```
var os = require('os');
    var static = require('node-static');
    var http = require('http');
    var socketIO = require('socket.io');

    var fileServer = new(static.Server)();

    var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        fileServer.serve(req, res);
    }).listen(2013);

    var io = socketIO.listen(app);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
     ...
     socket.on('join', function (message) {
      ...
     }
     ...
    }
```

i hope this help u